# What does ? and : mean in C++?

Tags: c++

For example I have this statement

```
return ( m > n ? m : n );
```

What does the question mark mean between `m > n` and `m : n`?
What does the colon in `m : n` mean?

Comment: google `C ternary operator` or `conditional expressions`

Comment: hint: in python it is written: `return m if m>n else n`

Comment: @H2CO3 and others: if y'all want to continue the debate, take it to [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) where it belongs.

Comment: I don't see why this question has such a massive downvote; +1

Comment: ? literally means "is `m > n?`", if it's true it returns `m`, if false it returns `n` in your example

Answer (score 3):

Its technical name is the conditional operator, and it's shorthand for `if-then;else`.

```
if m > n
  then m
  else n
```

or in actual C++ syntax:

```
if(m > n)
{
  return m;
} 
else 
{
  return n;
}
```

> What does the question mark mean between m > n and m : n? What does
>   the colon in m : n mean?

The `?` and `:` are part of the conditional operators syntax. The `?` indicates that the left expression should be a boolean evaluation `true` or `false`. The `:` delineates the `true` and `false` results. The left-hand of `:` is the result if the expression evaluates to `true` and the right-hand of `:` is the result if the expression is `false`

Comment: hah. Thanks :) typing and editing quickly, not thinking aboot proper grammar.

Comment: BTW, it also works on the LEFT side of assignment operator!

Comment: @franji1 it is not standard C. although it *is* standard C++.

Answer (score 0):

This is the ternary operator, it means if m is greater than n then do m otherwise do n, it is equivalent to:

```
 if(m>n) 
    return m; 
 else 
    return n;
```

Comment: And, for the record, the name of the operator is "conditional operator", not "the ternary operator".

Comment: it is *a* ternary operator :)

Comment: "if m is greater than n then do m otherwise do n" - no. maybe: "if m is greater than n then evaluate to m otherwise evaluate to n"

Comment: hm, i guess i was thinking 'do' as in expression. evaluate to is also wrong if you want to be exact. evaluate expression m would be exact..

Comment: this is the "lazy" part. so "evaluate m and then evaluate to that value" :)